# When are static function variables allocated?

Tags: c

I have a question in allocation of memory for static variables. Please look at the following snippet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void fun();

static int a;

void main()
{
    fun();
    getch();
}

void fun()
{
    static int b;
}
```

Can someone please explain me when memory will be allocated for `static int b` in function `fun` (before `main` is executed or when the function is located). I knew that memory for static will be allocated only once, but I want to knew when memory will be allocated for it. Please explain.

I am using  64 bit processor, turbo c compiler, windows 7 operating system.

Comment: Cleanup on aisle 5 please? I don't have that power yet.

Comment: Wow. It was being edited so fast I couldn't figure out what revision was right

Comment: regarding the edited-out request to e-mail you answers directly, this is a question _and answer_ site not a free, private consultation site. If you want, you can request to be notified of answers by e-mail.

Answer (score 8):

Memory for static variables is *allocated* when your program is loaded. Static variables in a function are *initialized* before the function is called for the first time.

Comment: In this case, since the value isn't specified, I would expect space to be allocated in the program's BSS segment. This is just a block of 0 initialised memory allocated by the loader at runtime.

Comment: I would not count on variables without initialization in the code, to be initialized to 0 on allocation.

Comment: @pascal, the standard (§6.7.8/10) requires that static arithmetic variables without an initializer be initialized to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Memory for statics is normally allocated basically as the program loads/just before it starts to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Memory for static variables (both a and b in the example question) is allocated at compile time.  You can verify this by examining your map file.  Be aware that, depending on the detail provided in the map file, you may not see the variable name of the static variable, rather simply that the corresponding amount of memory has been allocated.  They are initialized when the program is loaded along with the global variables...not the first time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

Statics live in the same place as globals. The space for them is set at compile time and allocated at load time.

Answer (score 0):

When `static` is used inside a function block, the keyword `static` changes the **storage class** of the variable or function, which means `static int b;` is saying that `b` is a **static** variable rather than an **automatic** one.

When talking about storage class, **static** one is initialized in static memory before the program runs, and is there all the time when the program runs, while **automatic** one is initialized in run-time stack or heap when reaches certain block and is destroyed when the program goes out of the block.

---

When `static` is used outside as in the `static int a;` shows, this is rather another case. It   changes the **linkage** of the variable to be **internal** while the default value is **external**. And it has nothing to do with the **storage class** of the variable or function.

With `static`, `a` is **internal**, which means it is only accessible to those within this file. Without `static`, `a` is set to be **external** by default, which means it is accessible to those within and out of the file where `a` is defined.

Answer (score -3):

There is no allocation for b in this case.  It is an int, and is added to the stack when the application is loaded.