# why static variable is allocated when program starts but initialize later?

Tags: c++

I'm new here, I see **Static variables in a function are initialized before the function is called for the first time.**, but I still don't know why it doesn't call the constructor before the function starts?

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    ~Base();

private:

};

Base::Base()
{
    cout << "I'm Base" << endl;
}

Base::~Base()
{
}
int main()
{
    cout << "start program!" << endl;
    static Base b;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: run result of the code]

[When are static function variables allocated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319753/when-are-static-function-variables-allocated), I think the case is almost the same with me..
Any help will be appreciated ^_^

Comment: From 6.7-p4 : "such a variable is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration; "

Comment: _"I see Static variables in a function are initialized before the function is called for the first time"_ Where do you see that? It is incorrect!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319753/when-are-static-function-variables-allocated, I saw here, I think the case is almost the same with me...

Comment: @CatTom That question is about C, while yours is about C++. Do not assume that things work exactly the same in the two, they are different languages.

Comment: @walnut thanks, so for C, it's right, for c++，it has other situation？

Comment: @CatTom In C, there are no class types or constructors that could be called and the initializer for a static variable must be a constant. It therefore doesn't matter when exactly they are initialized in C as long as it is before the first use. In C++ this is different because you can have side effects (such as your output).

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. Static variables are initialised *the first time* they are encountered, which of course is not necessarily at the start of a function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319753/when-are-static-function-variables-allocated , I saw here, I think the case is almost the same with me...

Comment: Congrats on 200k! :D

Answer (score 3):

Objects with static storage duration have two phases of initialisation: Static phase and dynamic phase. Some static variables don't have dynamic initialisation at all. Those objects that do have dynamic initialisation are initially statically zero-initialised.

The static phase of initialisation happens when the program starts, before anything else. Thus, memory must also have been allocated before anything else.

The dynamic phase of initialisation cannot be instantaneous. Dynamic initialisation may have dependencies on initialisation of other static objects. Some objects are necessarily initialised before other objects. This is why dynamic initialisation happens after allocation.

For namespace scope variables with static storage, their dynamic initialisation happens either before `main`, or it may be deferred later in which case it happens before anything from that same translation unit is accessed or called (in practice, deferral happens when dynamic loading is involved).

For static local variables...

> Static variables in a function are initialized before the function is called for the first time

Not exactly. Their dynamic initialisation always happens exactly when execution reaches them for the first time. That is always *after* the function is called; not before. For example:

```
void foo(bool bar)
{
    if (bar) {
        static T var;
    }
}
```

`var` will not be initialised even when the function is called, if the provided argument is `false`.

The order of dynamic initialisation across translation units is unspecified. This would otherwise make it impossible to safely rely on initialisation of objects with static storage from other translation units, but the "initialisation on first use" behaviour of static local variables is a feature that allows exact control over the order of their initialisation, making it possible to rely on their initialisation even across translation unit boundaries.

Comment: You mean initialization including memory allocating？so, dynamic initialization variables cannot be searched in memory when the execution doesn't reach them？

Answer (score 1):

I think, based on your comments, that the detail you are missing is that there are both global and local static variables.

Global static variables are initialized when the program is first loaded. Edit: Apparently this is not required behavior (though it is the most common) - initialization is allowed to be delayed. See comment by @walnut.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "start program!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

static Base b;
```

Output:

```
I'm Base
start program!
```

While static variables in functions are initialized the first time control passes over them. Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "start program!" << std::endl;
    static Base b;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
start program!
I'm Base
```

I have added a second example, as per @EvilTeach's comment, to show how the static is only initialized a single time despite multiple functioncalls. Also, added guard (from @eerorika's answer) to show how initialization only happens when execution actually reaches the variable.

```
void testFunc(bool test)
{
    std::cout << "testFunc called with: " << test << std::endl;
    if (test)
        static Base b;
}

int main()
{
    testFunc(false);
    testFunc(true);
    testFunc(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
testFunc called with: 0
testFunc called with: 1
I'm Base
testFunc called with: 1
```

Comment: This is not technically correct. It is standard-conform for the compiler to delay non-local static initialization until first odr-use of a non-local static variable in the translation. So in your second case it doesn't actually have to print in that order, although I don't know whether any compiler does it differently outside of shared libraries.

Comment: @EvilTeach Good suggestion.

Comment: @walnut Thank you, I did not know that. I added a note to my answer to read your comment.